# Radio button status is always 'checked'

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments, radio-button

Here is my code:

```
 RadioButton daysAsCustomerRadio = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.days_as_customers_radio);
     daysAsCustomerRadio.setOnClickListener(new RadioButtonHandler());

    //Action Listener for the Radio Button
        private class RadioButtonHandler implements OnClickListener
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                RadioButton checkedButton = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(view.getId());
                Log.d("CHECKED_STAT", "Button stat: "+daysAsCustomerRadio.isChecked());
Log.d("CHECKED_STAT_1", "Button stat: "+checkedButton .isChecked());

                if(checkedButton.isChecked())
                {
                    checkedButton.setChecked(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    checkedButton.setChecked(true);
                }


            }

        }
```

What I am trying to do is this.

1. If the user clicked on a selected radio button, then deselect it.
2. If the user clicked on a deselected radio button, then select it.

But the case is, the radio button status is always `true`, even when the radio button is not selected. I even tried to set it to false pragmatically first in `onCreateView()` (This is a `Fragment` class), but still, the same result.

Why is this?

PS. There are no `RadioGroups` and can't add as well.

Comment: change this line `RadioButton checkedButton = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(view.getId());` with `RadioButton checkedButton = (RadioButton)view`;

Comment: Use a check box instead of a radio button. Radio buttons are meant to be used in groups and there is always one in the group selected.

Comment: @Henry: I can't. I have a wireframe to work with

Comment: I'd talk to the designer. It is the wrong UI element for this use case.

Comment: @FlowOverStack sorry...what do you mean ?

Comment: @Ketan: It didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve this by using a trick. I have boolean variables to check whether the RadioButtons are checked or not.